# using {{ request.get_host }} in template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Template file that is located in one of the apps:

```
{% extends 'base_well_surfer.html' %}

{% block content %}

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><a href="http://{{ request.get_host }}">Back to home</a></td></tr>
        <tr><td><a href="{% url 'wellsurfer:search' %}">Dynamically search in Well Surfer Database</a></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

my goal is to have a link that takes me back to the homepage. 
Is there a more elegant way of creating the link other than hardcoding the "http://" in front of the "{{ request.get_host }}" in the template?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `<a href="/">`?

Comment: This works, thank you. I was reinventing the wheel.